# Gradient Descent

Tags: python, gradient-descent

I am trying to compute a function that calculates the gradient descent in python. I know how to compute it without vectors for example:

```
 def gradient_descent(x,y):
    m_curr = b_curr = 0
    iterations = 10000
    n = len(x)
    learning_rate = 0.08

for i in range(iterations):
    y_predicted = m_curr * x + b_curr
    cost = (1/n) * sum([val**2 for val in (y-y_predicted)])
    md = -(2/n)*sum(x*(y-y_predicted))
    bd = -(2/n)*sum(y-y_predicted)
    m_curr = m_curr - learning_rate * md
    b_curr = b_curr - learning_rate * bd
```

However, I'm having trouble when the parameters are vectors. Any help would be appreciated. I'm new to python

```
# computeMSEBatchGradient: 
#   weights - vector of weights (univariate linear = 2 weights)
#   features - vector (or matrix) of feature values
#   targets - vector of target values, same length as features
#
#   returns average gradient over the batch of features
def computeMSEBatchGradient(weights,features,targets):

  # insert calculation of gradient here
  #return the gradient as a vector


  return gradient
```

Comment: "I'm having trouble" doesn't show here: you've neglected to provide the code you *did* try.  You're question reduces to "write the vectorized code for me", which is out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I meant to ask how do I return the gradient from the function as a vector